# Not able to create a event in google calendar through android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to use the google calendar API for the first time and I want to add event to it on the click of a button 
I tried to read the documentation for the same and was able to follow up the quickstart it gave but android studio shows this error
Cannot resolve the symbol **service**. I was not able to understand the solution given in another post.Can someone please help me out?

You can find my code here:

```
 Event event = new Event().setSummary(name).setLocation(loc).setDescription(desc);
                DateTime startDate  = new DateTime(sd);
                EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDate(startDate);
                event.setStart(start);

                DateTime endDate = new DateTime(ed);
                EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime().setDate(endDate);
                event.setEnd(end);

                EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                        new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                        new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
                };
                Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                        .setUseDefault(false)
                        .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
                event.setReminders(reminders);

                String calendarId = "primary";
                event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
                System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
```

Comment: Which API are you following? I think this one is the correct method to insert an event through app: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event

Comment: @AlphaOne this will open the calendar app , i.e. providing the intent

Comment: I want to add directly from my app

Comment: using the google calendar api